# Configure letter opener preview path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project we have both `test` and `spec` folders, since we are trying to migrate from minitest to rspec.

I am now trying to preview the layout of a mailer I am designing, so I created a preview mailer. The thing is that it requires me to put my mailer previews in the `test/mailers/xx` path or else it won't find them.

Is there a way I can tell rails to search for the mailer previews at the `spec` folder instead?

So this is the preview I am talking about:

```
# Preview at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/reporting/iue/report_mailer/name
class Reporting::IUE::ReportMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def report
    report = FactoryBot.create(:reporting_iue_report)
    FactoryBot.create_list(:reporting_iue_report_section, 3, report: report)
    Reporting::IUE::ReportMailer.report(report)
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setup for `letter_opener` will actually store the temporary mailer test in `tmp/letter_opener`. That tells me that somewhere in your configuration, the path is setup to go to the `test` directory instead. I'd look for an initializer file or something that is specifying it.

Otherwise, you can create your own file such as `initializer/letter_opener.rb` and put the following in there:

```
LetterOpener.configure do |config|
  # To overrider the location for message storage.
  # Default value is <tt>tmp/letter_opener</tt>
  config.location = Rails.root.join('spec', 'mailers')
end
```

From there you can use the location to change it to where you want it. Please see the `letter_opener` [readme](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener#configuration) for more info.

**Update 1:**

Based on your comment, you don't actually need `letter_opener`. Letter opener is used to preview email in the browser during development and is a replacement for actually sending email.

What you seem to need to know is how to have the generators create files in the spec folder. If that's the case, you need to update your generators in the `config/application.rb` file. Specifically, change `test_framework` to `:rspec`. For example:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
  g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```

I've added the factory bot line since you've mentioned using that.

**Update 2:**

To change the path of where the mailer previews are, I believe you can do that by adding the following to the `config/applications.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailer_previews"
```

Please see more on that in the [Rails Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails).

Comment: But the tmp path is where it stores the already created emails, right? I'm talking about the path where you put the factory bot code to generate test records that the mailer will then use

Comment: You made me realize that what I was using was not a feature from letter opener, so thank you! But the factory bot thing was not really my issue. Even if the preview email is on the `test` folder and the factories on the `spec` it still works. The thing is that I want my previews to also be found on the spec folder

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon - ohhhhh got it. Please see update 2. :)

Comment: That's it! Last config did it.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

try this `config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/mailer_previews"`
or something like it.  [Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Previewing+emails) are some docs...

Comment: Yes! That was the answer, but John answered first, thank you!